# Detecting all installed SAPI voices

Tags: c#, c++, qt, sapi

When i use SpeechSynthesizer class in C# I get all voices installed in my system.
When i use COM-object-based SAPI in C++ I get only 4 of them (Microsoft Anna and 3 other from Microsoft).

Why is this happening?
I want to use Acapela voice in C++(QT), is it possible? If Yes, how?

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Use SysInternals' ProcMon to see SAPI look through the registry for the voices.  SpeechSynthesizer also uses SAPI so some odds that you'll see something else if you compile your C++ code to 64-bits.  Contact the voice vendor if you need more assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acapela voices are notorious for not having 64 bit support.  If you build your C++ app in 32 bit mode (Project menu/Properties/Platform - make sure it's set to Win32, and not x64), you should be able to see the Acapela voice.